# EntityFramework Add with duplicate children

Tags: .net, entity-framework

actually im having huge problems figuring out how to handle Adding/Updating complex Entities while Children can contain duplicates (with unique-keys).

I try to break the Problem down to the core:

Three Entities: GrandFather 1---* Father *--- * Children (1-many, many to many)

```
  public class GrandFather
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Father> RelatedChildren { get; set; }
    }
    public class Father
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public GrandFather RelatedFather;

        public ICollection<Child> RelatedChildren { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_TEST",0,IsUnique=true)]
        public String UniqueKeyPart1 { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_TEST", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        public String UniqueKeyPart2 { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Father> RelatedFathers { get; set; }
    }
```

So, actuall there are (eg.) 10 different Children and Father 1 can have the same children as Father 2. One Father can only have different Children (in this case Maximum 10)

Results in a Graph which contains a Grandfather, which contains multiple Fathers (all different), which contains multiple Children

**Problem:**
When i try to Add the Grandfather

```
context.Grandfather.Add(grandfather);
context.SaveChanges();
```

there will be an exception like "cannot add Child cause there are duplicates .. on Index IX_TEST.."

I expect (of course) that the EF inserts the Grandfather + all Fathers + their Relationships and the Children + their relationships to their fathers

Ive tried so many different ways (iterating over the children and attaching/detaching before/after inserting for eg.) that i cannot even list them up here.

**Question:**

What is the best practice to get this working properly? Im near to throwing this all away and using plain SQL/or creating the Relationships myself.

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to add to the database existing entities, so you get an Id exception.

I always find the best way to handle many-to-many relationships with code-first is to create mapping entities (that will generate the mapping tables).

My suggestion would be to create a FatherChild entity:

```
public class FatherChild
{
    [Key]
    public int FatherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Father Father {get;set;}
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Child { get; set; }
}
```

and then update your Father and Child classes:

```
public class Father
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public GrandFather RelatedFather;

    public ICollection<FatherChild> RelatedChildren { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // assuming that you only navigate from one entity you only need this ICollection on Father or Child, not on both
    public ICollection<FatherChild> RelatedFathers { get; set; }
}
```

The you should need to create a new mapping everytime you need one:
    var father;
    // get a father from the db or create a new one
    // same for child
    var fatherChild = new FatherChild {
        FatherId = father.Id, 
        ChildId=childId
    };

```
father.RelatedChildren.Add(fatherChild); //assuming that Father is your main entity and is the one holding the navigation property
// persist father in the db
```